# Why doesn't my bot doesn't accept my commands?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having issues building my music bot. It's accepting any of my commands.
I tried to making the Bot join the voice chat, and subsequently play music, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Here's my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', description="L's very own Jukebox", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} ({bot.user.id})")
    print("-----")


async def on_load():
    print(f"Starting to load cogs...")
    for cog in os.listdir("cog"):
        if cog.endswith(".py"):
            try:
                await bot.load_extension(f"cog.{cog.strip('py')}")
                print("{cog} cog has been loaded")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print("{cog} cog can't be loaded.")


load_dotenv('development.env')
on_ready()
on_load()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Here's also the code for the cog I'm using. It's under the 'cog' folder:

```py
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
import YTDLSource

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Ping!')

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("You're currently not in a voice channel!")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: ctx.send(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

            await ctx.send(f'Now playing {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def stream(self, ctx, *, url):

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def volume(self, ctx, volume: int):

        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("Not connected to a voice channel.")

        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = volume / 100
        await ctx.send(f"Changed volume to {volume}%")

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Paused ⏸")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resuming ▶")

    @commands.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx):

        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @play.before_invoke
    @stream.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You aren't connected to a voice channel!")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author is not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

Anything that can help me fix my bot would help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: assuming that u r having this cog file as `music.py`, and the thing is u r actually trying to let the code search the folder for cog files automatically and load them, which is very cool, but u have to change `cog.strip('py')` into `cog.strip('.py')` or `cog.replace('.py', '')` so that while loading a cog, the string goes in like `cog.music` bcuz right now, the string goes in like `cog.music.`. that unnessesary dot breaks the code and doesn't allow u to load the cog  properly (i guess, anyway give it a try)

Comment: I'm assuming you're on 2.0.0 (please correct me if I'm wrong) because you are awaiting bot loads. You have to `await on_load()`, doing `on_load()` doesn't actually execute like you think it does, it only creates the coroutine object that you have to await.

Comment: I'm now having an exception error. 
This is the exception error:

`
object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
{cog} cog can't be loaded.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you guys, you helped me find the issue. As it turns out, I don't need `await` in `on_ready()` method. I also fixed the `on_ready()` method overall.

There was also a typo in the code. I wrote `py`, instead of `.py` for the `bot.load_extension(f"cog.{cog.strip('.py')}")`.

So the code for the method looks like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} ({bot.user.id})")
    print("-----")
    print(f"Starting to load cogs...")
    for cog in os.listdir("cog"):
        if cog.endswith(".py"):
            try:
                bot.load_extension(f"cog.{cog.strip('.py')}")
                print("{cog} cog has been loaded")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print("{cog} cog can't be loaded.")
```